# Camel Recpient List and File/FTP Polling

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

I need to write a Camel route that poll a tones of ftp servers. The situation is pretty much the one described in this thread: http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/kuUDzQRmQQIof5y9zXzG

I am using Spring DSL and I don't seem to be able to piece things together. How are the templates mentioned in that thread relevant?

Even with the file protocol, I wasn't lucky. here is what i tried to create:

```
<from uri="file://C:/Temp?consumer.delay=1000"/>
            <recipientList parallelProcessing="true" delimiter=",">
                <simple>file://C:/Sampa?consumer.delay=1000</simple>
            </recipientList>
```

I keep getting an error:

Unknown file language syntax: //C:/Sampa?consumer.delay=1000

Any suggestion? Ideally, a simple route that uses recipient list and file or ftp would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in between the `<recipientList/>` tag must return the URI of the different recipients. In your case your `<simple/>` tag is constant and in fact not a reasonable URI that's why you get the `Unknown file language syntax: //C:/Sampa?consumer.delay=1000` error message.

A good approach is to use header that can be dynamically updated such as

```
<route>
    <from uri="file:src/data2?noop=true"/>
    <recipientList parallelProcessing="true" delimiter=",">
        <header>myHeader</header>
    </recipientList>
</route>
```

Find more information about the recipient list pattern [here](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html).

**EDIT:**

The `recipientList/>` is only used for the dynamic distribution of a message in a route to different targets. If you need to dynamically define sources such as different file directories or FTP servers, then you may setup the routes dynamically using Camel's Java API

```
pzbkuc class DynamicRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private final String[] fileNames;

    public DynamicRouteBuilder(final String[] fileNames) {
        this.fileNames = fileNames;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        for (final String fileName : this.fileNames) {
            from("file:" + fileName).to("file:targetDirectory");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I guess I am still confused. How do you go from the recipientList tag to actually processing the files. Say, I simply want to log the content of some files pulled from a list of ftp servers. Let's assume for now that the list is computed and put in aheader or is dynamically computer with simple. Where would you put that log instruction in your first example with recipientList above? Also, why is the above not a reasonable url? I guess I am still missing how to connect recipientList with file prducer or ftp producer.

Comment: I added an additional example. I hope it helps.

Comment: I suspect we are talking about two different things. It seems you are suggesting a mechanism to poll ONE single source and send input files to different recipients. What I want is a mechanism to poll MANY sources, download files from them and send them to ONE single recipient. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: In this case you don't need `<recipientList/>`, see my example.

Comment: How do you then deal with MANY DYNAMIC source URIs?

Comment: Use separate routes for every source and route them to the same target route. For the generation of the source routes I would recommend to use the Java API.

Comment: I haven't solved it yet. It is still on my desk. My hope is to find a camel only solution that would allow me to specify many URIs for ftp or file consumers.

Comment: What's wrong with my solution? It's simple. It's easy to implement.

Comment: Not quite what I was hoping for but is the best possible solution.